Hard error bounds for two-dimensional ODE integration
Consider the non-linear two-dimensional ODE $\dfrac{d\mathbf x}{dt}=-t\dfrac{\mathbf x}{|\mathbf x|}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, which can also be written as the system $x'(t)=-\frac{tx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, $y'(t)=-\frac{ty}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1$. Starting at any point $(x_0,y_0)$ at $t=0$, it will always reach the origin in some nonnegative time $t^*$, and my goal is to evaluate the function $t^*(x_0,y_0)$ to a high relative precision. However, to truly know the accuracy of my $t^*$ estimate, I need hard bounds on the global error introduced by numerically integrating the ODE.
There are several resources about estimating the global error, for Runge–Kutta and for other methods. However, there doesn't seem to be much about provably bounding the global error, much less for ODEs in more than one dimension. Presumably, this will involve looking into the structure of the equation, to bound the maximum local error at each step. But how exactly do I proceed?
One approach might be to reduce the problem to one dimension, by recasting the system as a second-order ODE for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$. First, dividing the two coordinates, we obtain $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+\frac1t\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}x\quad\text{and thus}\quad t=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y},$$ which yields $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac x{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y},\quad\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac y{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}-1.$$ Now, we can differentiate $\frac{dy}{dx}$ again, and substitute: $$\begin{split}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}&=\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^{-1}\frac d{dt}\frac{y+\frac1t\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}x\\&=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{x\frac{dx}{dt}}+\frac{x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt}}{xt\frac{dx}{dt}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{t^2x\frac{dx}{dt}}-\frac{(y+\frac1t\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{dx}{dt}}{x^2\frac{dx}{dt}}\\&=\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}x+\frac{(x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt})(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)}{x\frac{dx}{dt}(x^2+y^2)}-\frac{(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)^2}{x\frac{dx}{dt}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{y+(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)}{x^2}\\&=\frac{(x+y\frac{dy}{dx})(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)}{x(x^2+y^2)}+\frac{(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)^3}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\&=\frac{x\frac{dy}{dx}-y}{x^2}+\frac{y(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)^2}{x^2(x^2+y^2)}+\frac{(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)^3}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.\end{split}$$
However, this form isn't exactly ideal for numerical integration, since we have to take the limit as $y'_0\to-\infty$ to represent the initial conditions of the parametric form. We can alternatively solve for $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$, but the expression is more complicated: $$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=\frac x{y^2}+\frac{x(2x+y)(y\frac{dx}{dy}-x)}{y^2(x^2+y^2)}+\frac{(x^2+y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(y\frac{dx}{dy}-x)^2}{xy^2(x^2+y^2)}.$$
